# Dynamically extend pipe chains in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently practicing with streams in Node.js using the modules `through2`, `concat-stream` and `request`.

I set up a pipe chain like this:

```
request(process.argv[2])
.pipe(through(write, end))
.pipe(/*And */)
.pipe(/* Some */)
.pipe(/* more */)
.on("finish",function (){ #Do some stuff });

function write(buf, enc, nxt){ 
    /*Push some data after some processing*/
}
function end(done){ 
    done()
}
```

This is a static chain of pipes. Is it possible to, through some form of user input, dynamically specify a pipe-chain?

In pseudo code:

```
array_of_user_pipes = from_some_input;
pipe_library = {pipe_name:pipe_callback} object, loaded into application logic

perform the url request (fetch .txt file over the internet)
for all pipe in array_of_user_pipes do 
  fetch pipe from pipe_library (simple key look-up)
  chain pipe to chain
execute the (dynamic) pipe chain
```

Comment: It looks totally doable. Have you encountered any specific problems implementing this approach?

Comment: Just not really sure how to set it up, because static chains are set up through `method chaining`, this isn't possible if you're iterating, or is there another way to add a pipe to a chain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problems in translating your pseudo code to js

```
const pipesMap = {
   pipeName1: require('pipe-module'),
   pipeName2: function(){},
   ...
}
```

Define a `piper` function that takes pipe names and returns a function that pipe initial event stream through each of them.

```
const piper = pipes => request =>
      pipes.reduce((piped, pipe) => piped.pipe(pipesMap[pipe]), request)


const userInputPipesArray = ['pipeName1', 'pipeName2']

piper(userInputPipesArray)(request(process.argv[2])).on('finish')
```

**Edit**

You could do the same using for-loop

```
let piped = request(process.argv[2])

for(let pipe of userInputPipesArray) {
  piped = piped.pipe(pipeMap[pipe])
}

piped.on('finish', ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out. Does this approach have a certain name? I'd like to read up on it.

Comment: Not sure if there is any special name for when `reduce` aka `fold` is used this way. This could be done w/o reduce using for-loop.

Comment: Thanks. This looks exactly like the way I wanted, perhaps I was too pessimistic :)